# How to access fields in object?

Tags: java, json, rest, class, reflection

```
@When("^the service is called$")
    public void service() throws Throwable {
         Response response = serviceCaller.get(serviceUrl + nameId);
        GroupInfoModel groupInfoModel = response.readEntity(GorupInfoModel.class);
    }

    @Then("^I should see$")
    public void i_should_see(List<String> nameList) throws Throwable {
        NameHeaderModel person = GroupInfoModel.getPerson();

        Field[] declaredFields = person.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field fieldList : declaredFields) {
            assertTrue(nameList.contains(fieldList.getName()));
        }
}
```

So I have a wrapper class GroupInfoModel which gets persons and entities of  `NameHeaderModel` class. 
I wanted to know if there is a better way to access fields in person class after the response and compare it. I'm writing a simple rest service to send json object and then consuming it from this response.

**EDIT:** So the `NameHeaderModel` will have fields in it like `id, name, address`. I want to compare those fields with fields in `List<String> nameList`, which is coming from a feature file.

So my question what is a better way to access fields because reflections can be an expensive operation?

Comment: I don't get it. You have the class. It contains the declared fields. That's not going to change with every request. It's only going to change when you change the class and redeploy the application. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I edited the description, does that kinda make sense?

Comment: And that is List<String>nameList. Somehow <String> isn't getting recognized.

Comment: I still don't get it. All you're checking is that the features file agrees with the definition of the class. The point of the file escapes me. Are you perhaps wanting to check that the fields concerned *aren't empty?*

Comment: So basically, i have some fields listed in feature file. And json object will be produced with those same fields. I want to check if that json object will have the same fields as the feature file. And then those fields aren't empty, that could be further check.

Comment: This isn't making sense. You have a Java class. It will always have the same fields, until you alter it and recompile it and redeploy the application. The 'feature file' is completely unnecessary, and just one more thing to go wrong. It seems to me that the class should be a bean and that it should use annotations like `@NotNull`, if your system supports those. Otherwise you need to check the fields yourself, and you don't need reflection for that if you know what the class is.

Comment: Yeah i agree. I have validationUtil class which checks the fields. 
Here i just wanted to check my rest service and if it's producing the right json object or not.